# Table column width unexpectedly shortened

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table (populated from a datatable on server side), with no styling except background color, and for some reason it breaks some of the lines.
Is there any CSS behavior that dictates this? I tried to replicate it with a table populated with a random string of "M "s, and it also broke the line after every space...

EDIT:

What's happening:

|M|M|
|M|M|
|M|M|

What's supposed to happen:

|M M M |M M M |

Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't very helpful, because there's no screenshot or visual representation of what's happening, other than a vague description. What specifically is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the NOWRAP option.

```
<table><tr><td NOWRAP>Text</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Yes... That is what I meant.. Thanks! Also, is there a way to do this in an external CSS file?

Comment: Yes there is:

<table>
<tr class="nowrap">
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

CSS:

tr.nowrap { white-space:nowrap; }
td { white-space:inherit; }


or google: nowrap css